# What is the waiting time for a Green Card in the EB2 category for people born in countries within the European Union?

Tags: usa, greencard, h1-visa

If you were born in Germany (for example), and you are on a H1B visa and your employer is willing you to sponsor you for a green card ?

Comment: The [December 2016 visa bulletin](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/law-and-policy/bulletin/2017/visa-bulletin-for-december-2016.html) says that the 2nd preference work-based visas are current. Within a year, maybe? It'll depend on where you're filing. Los Angles, for example, is busier than say, Minneapolis, usually.

Comment: Where are you filing? From EU or in the US? Mail in?